# Pass jquery variable to html file using attr

Tags: php, jquery, html

this is my_js.js file :

```
function updates() {
     $.getJSON("php/fetch.php", function(data) {
       $.each(data.result, function(){

          $( ".mes" ).attr( "onclick","ter('this['sender_id'')"]")  
 });
 });
}
```

and this is index.php file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<button class="mes" onclick="ter('my_js_variable')"> send</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ter(a) {
alert(a ) ;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my code but the variable doesn't passed to my html code.

Comment: this looks odd for several reasons `$( ".mes" ).attr( "onclick","ter('this['sender_id'')"]")  `

Comment: And your question is? So far you only describe what happens. Perhaps the *but* is a slight hint that you expected something different, but you don't say what and for what reason. Also you're not describing any trouble-shooting.

Comment: And load jQuery before you load your jQuery dependent script.

Comment: `"ter('this['sender_id'')"]"` - There was a cat on your keyboard. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You not specified your problem in detail. But I looked your code. I got an error regarding following line 
    $( ".mes" ).attr( "onclick","ter('this['sender_id'')"]")

But I removed that error.

JS file my_js.js should as follows :

```
function updates() {
 $.getJSON("php/fetch.php", function(data) {
 $.each(data.result, function(){
  $( ".mes" ).attr( "onclick","ter('this['sender_id'')]'") ; 
  });
 });
}
```

PHP File is as follows :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <button class="mes" onclick="ter('my_js_variable')"> send</button>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function ter(a) {
  alert(a ) ;
 }
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="my_js.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

If  your problem is not resolved, then specify details of your problem.